# Django: TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting below error when I pass the invalid credentials.

***TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'***

I don't understand it.

Here is the view.

View:

```
class LogInView(TemplateView):
template_name = "login.html"

@staticmethod
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    username_or_email = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    if '@' in username_or_email:
        username = User.objects.get(email=username_or_email).username
    else:
        username = username_or_email
    if username and password:
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Sorry, wrong username or password.')
            return render(request, self.template_name)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Username and Password cannot be blank.')
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Here is the url.
Url:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from sa.views import (
    LandingPageView,
    LogInView,
    LogOutView,
)


urlpatterns = [
    path('', LandingPageView.as_view(), name='LandingPageView'),
    path('login', LogInView.as_view(), name='LogInView'),
    path('logout', LogOutView.as_view(), name='LogOutView'),
]
```

Please help.

Comment: why have you made it a static method?

Comment: When you include an error message in your post, please include the entire error message including traceback. It includes useful information that you have skipped such as file/function names and line numbers.

Comment: As for the actual cause, it's likely because you've made a method static but left the `self` parameter there, which will not be supplied to it.

Comment: you know that django have a built in loginview that can make all that for you ?  [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Comment: It is now working fine by removing static method. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: since this is a static method, the first parameter is `request`.